Добавление приложения собранного в pyinstaller в графический киоск в astra linux 1.8
Мне нужно добавить в графический киоск приложение собранное в pyinstaller. Но при добавлении возникает эта ошибка. А в киоске данное приложение не отображается.
Приложение в не графического киоска запускается нормально.
В asta linux 1.7 все работает, в 1.8 нет.
